# UWP: Cannot access menu Checkbox from Code-Behind

Tags: uwp

I've created a menu with 3 Checkboxes in it: "menuRefreshFast", "menuRefreshMedium", and "menuRefreshSlow".

```
          <controls:MenuItem Header="UI" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="103">
                <CheckBox x:Name="menuRefreshFast" Content="Fast"></CheckBox>
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Name="menuRefresh" Text="Refresh Rate">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="menuRefreshFast" Content="Fast (250ms)" Click="menuRefreshFast_Click" Tag="menuRefreshFast"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="menuRefreshMedium" Content="Medium (500ms)" Click="menuRefreshMedium_Click" Tag="menuRefreshMedium"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="menuRefreshSlow" Content="Slow (1s)" Click="menuRefreshSlow_Click" Tag="menuRefreshSlow"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
            </controls:MenuItem>
```

When I load the app I can see the GUI doing the right thing. However when I try to reference these Checkboxes using the x:Name, it doesn't recognize them! Can someone explain to me why?

[screenshot: Code-behind doesn't recognize the Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Nz0.jpg)

Comment: Can you brief on why you want to access CheckBox from code-behind?

Comment: @Dishant I want checking of one box to uncheck the other 2 boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the control in the XAML ControlTemplate from the page code behind using the control's name directly. The [ControlTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.controltemplate) defines the element tree that is used as the control template for a control, its children elements don't exposed to your page to make you access it from page's code behind. Generally, we use the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) Class, you can find more info about it from internet. You can also use the way from @Dishant to get the CheckBox in your this case.

But if you want to make the selected items mutually exclusive, I will suggest you to use the [Radio buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/radio-button), you can group the Radio buttons to make users can only select one radio button in a radio button group. See the [Create a radio button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/radio-button#create-a-radio-button) part to make Radio buttons work in groups.

Here is the example code base on your code above.

```xml
        <controls:Menu>
            <controls:MenuItem Header="UI" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" TabIndex="103">
                <CheckBox x:Name="menuRefreshFast" Content="Fast"></CheckBox>
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem x:Name="menuRefresh" Text="Refresh Rate">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <RadioButton x:Name="menuRefreshFast" GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Fast (250ms)" Click="menuRefreshFast_Click" Tag="menuRefreshFast"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <RadioButton x:Name="menuRefreshMedium"  GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Medium (500ms)" Click="menuRefreshMedium_Click" Tag="menuRefreshMedium"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                <RadioButton x:Name="menuRefreshSlow"  GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Slow (1s)" Click="menuRefreshSlow_Click" Tag="menuRefreshSlow"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
            </controls:MenuItem>
        </controls:Menu>
```

Comment: Thank you, the Radio Button works well for my purposes! I will have to spend some time studying the Control Template stuff you referred to, but in the meantime this does the job in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't this so that there's direct approach to access the items inside ControlTemplate, but as a simple solution what you can do is, on loaded event of your CheckBox you can save that object as below:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="menuRefreshFast" Content="Fast (250ms)" Click="menuRefreshFast_Click" Tag="menuRefreshFast" Loaded="menuRefreshFast_Loaded"/>

private CheckBox menuRefreshFast;
private void menuRefreshFast_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   menuRefreshFast = sender as CheckBox;
}
```

Comment: Thanks as well for the workaround. I had seen people use it from other sites I researched, but was trying to avoid this way as it's not the cleanest. I may have to use this way for some other code that I am trying to fix however.